# installing CGAL with Qt5 on mac os el capitan failed

Tags: qt5, osx-elcapitan, cgal, qt5.6

I am trying to install CGAL 4.7 with Qt5 on Mac Os El Capitan. After a cmake in the build directory the configuration is the following :

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 7.0.0.7000176
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 7.0.0.7000176
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
== Setting paths ==
-- Build CGAL from release in directory CGAL-4.7
-- Packagenames: CGAL-4.7
== Setting paths (DONE) ==

== Generate version files ==
-- CGAL_MAJOR_VERSION=4
-- CGAL_MINOR_VERSION=7
-- CGAL_BUGFIX_VERSION=0
-- CGAL_SONAME_VERSION=11
-- CGAL_SOVERSION     =11.0.1
-- CGAL_REFERENCE_CACHE_DIR=
-- Building shared libraries
-- Targetting Unix Makefiles
-- Using /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ compiler.
-- DARWIN_VERSION=15
-- Mac Leopard detected
-- USING CMake version: 3.4.3
-- System: Darwin
== Generate version files (DONE) ==

== Set up flags ==
-- Build type: Release
-- USING CXXFLAGS = ' -O3 -DNDEBUG'
-- USING LDFLAGS = ' '
== Set up flags (DONE) ==

== Detect external libraries ==
-- External libraries supported: GMP;GMPXX;MPFR;ZLIB;OpenGL;LEDA;MPFI;RS;RS3;OpenNL;Eigen3;BLAS;LAPACK;QGLViewer;ESBTL;Coin3D;NTL;IPE
-- Preconfiguring library: GMP ...
-- Found GMP: /usr/local/lib/libgmp.dylib  
-- GMP has been preconfigured:
--   UseGMP-file:      
--   GMP include:      /usr/local/include
--   GMP libraries:    /usr/local/lib/libgmp.dylib
--   GMP definitions:  
-- USING GMP_VERSION = '6.1.0'
-- Preconfiguring library: MPFR ...
-- Found MPFR: /usr/local/lib/libmpfr.dylib  
-- MPFR has been preconfigured:
--   UseMPFR-file:      
--   MPFR include:      /usr/local/include
--   MPFR libraries:    /usr/local/lib/libmpfr.dylib
--   MPFR definitions:  
-- USING MPFR_VERSION = '3.1.3'
-- Boost version: 1.60.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   thread
--   system
-- Boost include:     /usr/local/include
-- Boost libraries:   /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread-mt.dylib;/usr/local/lib/libboost_system-mt.dylib
-- Boost definitions: 
-- USING BOOST_VERSION = '1.60.0'
== Detect external libraries (DONE) ==

== Write compiler_config.h ==
-- Performing Test CGAL_CFG_BOOST_VARIANT_SWAP_BUG - Success
-- Performing Test CGAL_CFG_DENORMALS_COMPILE_BUG - Success
-- Performing Test CGAL_CFG_FPU_ROUNDING_MODE_UNWINDING_VC_BUG - Success
-- Performing Test CGAL_CFG_IEEE_754_BUG - Success
-- Performing Test CGAL_CFG_ISTREAM_INT_BUG - Success
-- Performing Test CGAL_CFG_MATCHING_BUG_5 - Success
-- Performing Test CGAL_CFG_MATCHING_BUG_6 - Success
-- Performing Test CGAL_CFG_MATCHING_BUG_7 - Success
-- Performing Test CGAL_CFG_MATCHING_BUG_8 - Success
-- Performing Test CGAL_CFG_NESTED_CLASS_FRIEND_DECLARATION_BUG - Failed
-- Performing Test CGAL_CFG_NO_LIMITS - Success
-- Performing Test CGAL_CFG_NO_NEXTAFTER - Success
-- Performing Test CGAL_CFG_NO_STL - Success
-- Performing Test CGAL_CFG_NO_WARNING_CPP_DIRECTIVE_BUG - Success
-- Performing Test CGAL_CFG_NUMERIC_LIMITS_BUG - Success
-- Performing Test CGAL_CFG_OUTOFLINE_MEMBER_DEFINITION_BUG - Success
-- Performing Test CGAL_CFG_TEMPLATE_IN_DEFAULT_PARAMETER_BUG - Success
-- Performing Test CGAL_CFG_TYPENAME_BEFORE_DEFAULT_ARGUMENT_BUG - Success
-- Performing Test CGAL_CFG_USING_BASE_MEMBER_BUG_2 - Success
== Write compiler_config.h (DONE) ==

== Generating build files ==
Configuring libCGAL
-- Requested component: MPFR
-- Requested component: GMP
libCGAL is configured
-- Sources for CGAL component library 'CGAL_Core' detected
Configuring libCGAL_Core
-- Requested component: MPFR
-- Requested component: GMP
libCGAL_Core is configured
-- Sources for CGAL component library 'CGAL_ImageIO' detected
Configuring libCGAL_ImageIO
-- Found OpenGL: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework  
-- Found ZLIB: /opt/local/lib/libz.dylib (found version "1.2.8") 
-- OpenGL include:     /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework
-- OpenGL libraries:   /System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework;/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework
-- USING ZLIB_VERSION = '1.2.8'
-- Requested component: MPFR
-- Requested component: GMP
libCGAL_ImageIO is configured
-- Sources for CGAL component library 'CGAL_Qt3' detected
-- Sources for CGAL component library 'CGAL_Qt5' detected
Configuring libCGAL_Qt5
-- libCGAL_Qt5 is missing the dependencies: Qt5OpenGL Qt5Svg Qt5 cannot be configured.
-- Sources for CGAL component libraries 'CGAL_Core;CGAL_ImageIO;CGAL_Qt3;CGAL_Qt5' detected
== Generating build files (DONE) ==

-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/pratyuze/Libraries/CGAL-4.7/build
```

Following this, I point it to the proper location of Qt5 installation via ccmake, and then i do a make. This gives the following output:

```
    Scanning dependencies of target CGAL
[  4%] Building CXX object src/CGAL/CMakeFiles/CGAL.dir/all_files.cpp.o
[  8%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libCGAL.dylib
[  8%] Built target CGAL
Scanning dependencies of target CGAL_Core
[ 12%] Building CXX object src/CGAL_Core/CMakeFiles/CGAL_Core.dir/all_files.cpp.o
[ 16%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libCGAL_Core.dylib
[ 16%] Built target CGAL_Core
Scanning dependencies of target CGAL_ImageIO
[ 20%] Building CXX object src/CGAL_ImageIO/CMakeFiles/CGAL_ImageIO.dir/all_files.cpp.o
[ 25%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libCGAL_ImageIO.dylib
[ 25%] Built target CGAL_ImageIO
[ 29%] Generating qrc_Triangulation_2.cpp
[ 33%] Generating __/__/include/CGAL/Qt/moc_GraphicsViewNavigation.cpp
[ 37%] Generating __/__/include/CGAL/Qt/moc_DemosMainWindow.cpp
[ 41%] Generating __/__/include/CGAL/Qt/moc_GraphicsItem.cpp
[ 45%] Generating __/__/include/CGAL/Qt/moc_GraphicsViewInput.cpp
[ 50%] Generating qrc_CGAL.cpp
[ 54%] Generating qrc_Input.cpp
[ 58%] Generating qrc_File.cpp
Scanning dependencies of target CGAL_Qt5
[ 62%] Building CXX object src/CGAL_Qt5/CMakeFiles/CGAL_Qt5.dir/all_files.cpp.o
In file included from /Users/pratyuze/Libraries/CGAL-4.7/build/src/CGAL_Qt5/all_files.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/pratyuze/Libraries/CGAL-4.7/src/CGAL_Qt5/debug.cpp:22:
In file included from /Users/pratyuze/Libraries/CGAL-4.7/src/CGAL_Qt5/../../include/CGAL/Qt/debug.h:28:
In file included from /Users/pratyuze/Softwares/qt5/qtbase/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/QString:1:
In file included from /Users/pratyuze/Softwares/qt5/qtbase/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qstring.h:43:
/Users/pratyuze/Softwares/qt5/qtbase/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qrefcount.h:48:22: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
    inline bool ref() Q_DECL_NOTHROW {
                     ^
In file included from /Users/pratyuze/Libraries/CGAL-4.7/build/src/CGAL_Qt5/all_files.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/pratyuze/Libraries/CGAL-4.7/src/CGAL_Qt5/debug.cpp:22:
In file included from /Users/pratyuze/Libraries/CGAL-4.7/src/CGAL_Qt5/../../include/CGAL/Qt/debug.h:28:
In file included from /Users/pratyuze/Softwares/qt5/qtbase/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/QString:1:
/Users/pratyuze/Softwares/qt5/qtbase/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qstring.h:65:1: error: unknown type name 'Q_FORWARD_DECLARE_CF_TYPE'
Q_FORWARD_DECLARE_CF_TYPE(CFString);
^
/Users/pratyuze/Softwares/qt5/qtbase/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qstring.h:86:44: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
    Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline QLatin1String() Q_DECL_NOTHROW : m_size(0), m_data(Q_NULLPTR) {}
                                           ^
/Users/pratyuze/Softwares/qt5/qtbase/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qstring.h:96:51: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
    inline bool operator!=(const QString &s) const Q_DECL_NOTHROW;
                                                  ^
/Users/pratyuze/Softwares/qt5/qtbase/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qstring.h:97:50: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
    inline bool operator>(const QString &s) const Q_DECL_NOTHROW;
                                                 ^
/Users/pratyuze/Softwares/qt5/qtbase/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qstring.h:98:50: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
    inline bool operator<(const QString &s) const Q_DECL_NOTHROW;
                                                 ^
/Users/pratyuze/Softwares/qt5/qtbase/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qstring.h:99:51: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
    inline bool operator>=(const QString &s) const Q_DECL_NOTHROW;
                                                  ^
/Users/pratyuze/Softwares/qt5/qtbase/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qstring.h:100:51: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
    inline bool operator<=(const QString &s) const Q_DECL_NOTHROW;
                                                  ^
/Users/pratyuze/Softwares/qt5/qtbase/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qstring.h:128:9: error: unknown type name 'QTypedArrayData'
typedef QTypedArrayData<ushort> QStringData;
        ^
/Users/pratyuze/Softwares/qt5/qtbase/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qstring.h:128:24: error: expected unqualified-id
typedef QTypedArrayData<ushort> QStringData;
                       ^
/Users/pratyuze/Softwares/qt5/qtbase/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qstring.h:154:1: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(sizeof(qunicodechar) == 2,
^
/Users/pratyuze/Softwares/qt5/qtbase/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qstring.h:195:5: error: unknown type name 'QArrayData'
    QArrayData str;
    ^
/Users/pratyuze/Softwares/qt5/qtbase/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qstring.h:198:5: error: unknown type name 'QStringData'
    QStringData *data_ptr() const
    ^
/Users/pratyuze/Softwares/qt5/qtbase/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qstring.h:201:27: error: unknown type name 'QStringData'
        return const_cast<QStringData *>(static_cast<const QStringData*>(&str));
                          ^
/Users/pratyuze/Softwares/qt5/qtbase/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qstring.h:201:60: error: unknown type name 'QStringData'
        return const_cast<QStringData *>(static_cast<const QStringData*>(&str));
                                                           ^
/Users/pratyuze/Softwares/qt5/qtbase/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qstring.h:207:5: error: unknown type name 'QStringData'; did you mean 'QStringDataPtr'?
    QStringData *ptr;
    ^
/Users/pratyuze/Softwares/qt5/qtbase/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qstring.h:205:8: note: 'QStringDataPtr' declared here
struct QStringDataPtr
       ^
/Users/pratyuze/Softwares/qt5/qtbase/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qstring.h:213:13: error: unknown type name 'QStringData'; did you mean 'QStringDataPtr'?
    typedef QStringData Data;
            ^
/Users/pratyuze/Softwares/qt5/qtbase/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qstring.h:205:8: note: 'QStringDataPtr' declared here
struct QStringDataPtr
       ^
/Users/pratyuze/Softwares/qt5/qtbase/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qstring.h:215:21: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
    inline QString() Q_DECL_NOTHROW;
                    ^
/Users/pratyuze/Softwares/qt5/qtbase/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qstring.h:220:36: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
    inline QString(const QString &) Q_DECL_NOTHROW;
                                   ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [src/CGAL_Qt5/CMakeFiles/CGAL_Qt5.dir/all_files.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/CGAL_Qt5/CMakeFiles/CGAL_Qt5.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any help on why this is happening will be greatly appreciated. My feeling is this is due to the compiler i am using, because when I try to install this on a linux machine, it goes without a glitch.

Regards

Pratyush

Comment: What version of Qt5 are you using? Our mac testsuite machine is using 5.5.1

Comment: You have a problem of installation of QT5 : cf the cmake message -- libCGAL_Qt5 is missing the dependencies: Qt5OpenGL Qt5Svg Qt5 cannot be configured. You need to install the corresponding qt5 libraries.

Comment: @sloriot : i am using Qt 5.6.0. Do you suggest using Qt 5.5.1?

Comment: @gdamiand : thats the first run of cmake configuration for CGAL. indeed it does not find the required dependencies. After that, i manually direct it to the required libraries. thats why it even goes to the compilation stage. if that were not so, it would simply not even try to compile libCGAL_Qt5

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

`cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$(brew --prefix qt5)` which I took from this [link](https://github.com/Cockatrice/Cockatrice/issues/205).